# How to Defer css

Tags: css, wordpress, deferred

I have a website where my complete css is in one style.css, but I have some other plugins like, hotjar, wisita, its impacting on my website speed score.
I wanted to know how to Defer non-critical CSS so I can improve website score, I have one google font as well which is also impacting on score. Website is in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Use Autoptimize plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/

There in options you can defer any css styles that you want
Setting "Inline and Defer CSS?"

And also do a lot of other things for website optimization with this plugin